# Can someone identify what this toolbar for an editable div could potentially be?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, toolbar, contenteditable

I was working with the ability to paste images into a div where it would then be uploaded via a post request. So far it seems to be working, but I noticed this toolbar that seems to show up when I make the content editable. As a result of this, the user is able to manipulate the div beyond just pasting an image which is what I do not want them to do.

```html
<div tabindex="1" id="pasteZone" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return false">
  <span id="pasteMessage">Right click and paste an image, or click and press (ctrl+v for windows or ⌘+V for Mac)</span>
</div>
```

I need the paste zone to be editable so that the windows context menu allows for the option to paste the screenshot and have the option to ctrl+v or what have you. But I also do not want my users to be able to add text. It seems that I am able to do that successfully as far as key presses go, but the toolbar destroys that possibility.

What I have done:

I looked online to see if other examples of this occurred but I could not find anything on this particular issue. I checked to see if this was the standard for any contenteditable enabled div, but it is not. Other websites that have this do not show this toolbar.This leads me to believe that this has something to do with Bootstrap. If this is the case, how would I prevent this toolbar from showing?

Image:

[image]

Comment: That toolbar is not a native HTML or browser thing. It must be something your environment adds. It does not appear in the demo above.

Comment: Looks like ckeditor but it might just be similar icons

Comment: Or WordPress. You're not on a CMS, by chance?

Comment: @isherwood no, I am in a full dev environment. Not a CMS

Comment: What IDE? Browser extensions?

Comment: Right-click and inspect the toolbar elements. There should be clues as to its origin in the markup, such as custom classes or data attributes.